# Nth-child on carousel not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, slider

I am creating a slider and I am trying to apply styles to each slide that is in that position.
I don't know why but the nth-child doesn't work... this is what I was tying: `.slick-track .slick-active:nth-child(1)`
Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: try .slick-track > div.slick-active:first-child .

Comment: it doesn't work... I think it has something to do with the slick-active class because it is added through JS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer, in case someone needs it.

The slider was showing 3 slides on the screen with this class `slick-active` so I needed to apply styles to each slide, but nth-child wasn't working.

It can be solved with CSS:

```
.slick-active (For the first slide)

.slick-active + .slick-active (For the second slide)

.slick-active + .slick-active + .slick-active (For the third slide)
```

Comment: Nice use of the cascade. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".slick-active").first().css("background-color", "green");
```

```css
.slick {
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
}

.slick-active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="slick">
  </div>
  <div class="slick slick-active">
  </div>
  <div class="slick slick-active">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can select the three diferent `.slick-active` divs with:

- `.slick-track div[data-slick-index="-1"]`
- `.slick-track div[data-slick-index="0"]`
- `.slick-track div[data-slick-index="1"]`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that data doesn't change when the slide moves, so it's fixed for each slide.

Answer (score 0):

You can try inline style for all three slides along with !important .